# gnome-shell-extension-dock doesn't work in Fedora 16

Tags: fedora, gnome-shell

This extension is [supposed](http://www.micahcarrick.com/gnome3-shell-taskbar-dock.html) to make a Unity-like launch bar appear in the Fedora 16 desktop. I installed it from the Fedora repositories, logged out, logged in, and it doesn't appear. gnome-tweak-tool doesn't even list it as installed:

[image: gnome-tweak-tool screenshot]

The file listing for gnome-shell-extension-dock is:

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.dock.gschema.xml
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dock@gnome-shell-extensions.gnome.org
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dock@gnome-shell-extensions.gnome.org/extension.js
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dock@gnome-shell-extensions.gnome.org/metadata.json
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dock@gnome-shell-extensions.gnome.org/stylesheet.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest GNOME 3.2 uses new shell extension syntax so “old” GNOME 3.0 extensions don’t work on Fedora 16 or UBUNTU 11.10 using GNOME 3.2

Even when you copy extension to your

```
/home/username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

folder extensions are disabled by default.

To enable them you need to use the `gsettings` command from the terminal.

For example download, extract and copy the `noa11y@fpmurphy.com` extension to your extensions folder.

Then enable extension with gsettings command:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['noa11y@fpmurphy.com']"
```

Source: [Installing and enabling GNOME-Shell 3.2 Extensions](http://fusionlinux.org/2011/11/07/installing-and-enabling-gnome-shell-3-2-extensions/)

So, enable your extension this way:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['dock@gnome-shell-extensions.gnome.org']"
```